# node-sqlite3 doesn't concat string

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to do

```
sqlite.run("UPDATE room_stats SET words = words || ?, duration = duration + ?, guesses = guesses + ? WHERE id = ?", ["word|", 1, 1, 1])
```

but SQLite are not appending `word` to `words`.

The other fields are ok, only "words" that doesnt concat.
Am I doing it wrong or it's a bug?

I related this on GitHub too, but 6 days passed and no one answered:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/735

Running sqlite3 3.1.8 on NodeJS v7.1.0

---

I've temporarily solved using printf, in this case `printf('%s%s', words, 'word')`, but use a function is not recommended when I have an operator for this.

Comment: That looks ok. Are you getting an error? Are the other columns updating?

Comment: No error, and the other columns are updating normally.

Comment: I've temporarily solved using printf, in this case `printf('%s%s', word, 'word')`, but use a function is not recommended when I have an operator for this.